# Copy file to sharepoint

Tags: development, sharepoint-foundation

Below is my method which is meant to copy a file from a folder on my desktop to the sharepoint document library shared documents.

Its giving me error on SaveChanges method call, error shows me this

> "There is no file with URL 'http://---------/division1/shared
>   documents/strikers_logo.jpg' in this Web  " "An error occurred while
>   processing this request."

```
 public void copytosharepoint()
        {
            try
            {
                ChsmainDataContext sharePoint = new ChsmainDataContext(new Uri("http://rajum-pc:40613/_vti_bin/listdata.svc"));
                sharePoint.Credentials = System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;

                using (FileStream file = File.Open(@"C:\Users\rmirani\Downloads" + workflowProperties.Item.File.Name, FileMode.Open))
                {

                    string path = "/division1/shared documents/"+workflowProperties.Item.File.Name;
                    string contentType = workflowProperties.Item.ContentType.Name;

                    SharedDocumentsItem documentItem = new SharedDocumentsItem()
                    {
                        ContentType = contentType,
                        Name = workflowProperties.Item.File.Name,
                        Path = path,
                        Title = workflowProperties.Item.File.Title
                    };

                    sharePoint.AddToSharedDocuments(documentItem);

                    sharePoint.SetSaveStream(documentItem, file, false, contentType, path);

                    sharePoint.SaveChanges();
                }

                // stream.Flush();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                SPDiagnosticsService.Local.WriteTrace(0, new SPDiagnosticsCategory("RHM Test Logs", TraceSeverity.Unexpected, EventSeverity.Error), TraceSeverity.Unexpected, ex.Message, null);

            }
        }
```

Comment: Unfortunately with no information of how ChsmainDataContext is internally trying to save the document to SharePoint library, it is pretty impossible to say what could be wrong :(

Comment: chsmaindatacontext is a sharepoint service Listdata.svc,

Answer (score 3):

Apologies for not giving direct answer, but an alternative suggestion instead.

Would using [copy.asmx](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-NZ/sharepoint2010programming/thread/28495419-fa52-4fa0-bb7d-9f15092dc8ef) be option?

"The copy web service enables you to create new documents and send the metadata for indexing in one call."

```
public static void CreateNewDocumentWithCopyService(string destUrl, string filename, byte[] fileContent) 
    { 
      CopySoapClient c = new CopySoapClient();
      c.UseDefaultCredentials = true;

      byte[] myBinary = fileContent;
      string destination = destUrl + "/" + filename; 
      string[] destinationUrl = { destination }; 

      CopyService.FieldInformation info1 = new CopyService.FieldInformation(); 
      info1.DisplayName = "Title"; 
      info1.InternalName = "Title"; 
      info1.Type = CopyService.FieldType.Text; 
      info1.Value = "new title"; 

      CopyService.FieldInformation info2 = new CopyService.FieldInformation(); 
      info2.DisplayName = "Modified By"; 
      info2.InternalName = "Editor"; 
      info2.Type = CopyService.FieldType.User; 
      //info2.Value = "-1;#servername\\testmoss"; 
      info2.Value = "-1;servername\\alex";

      CopyService.FieldInformation[] info = { info1, info2 }; 
      CopyService.CopyResult resultTest = new CopyService.CopyResult(); 
      CopyService.CopyResult[] result = { resultTest }; 

      try 
      { 

        //c.CopyIntoItems(destination, destinationUrl, info, myBinary, out result); 
        //c.CopyIntoItemsAsync(destination, destinationUrl, info, myBinary);
      } 
      catch (Exception ex) 
      { 

      } 

    }
```

Alternate code:

```
string file = "C:\Users\rmirani\Downloads" + workflowProperties.Item.File.Name;
    CreateNewDocumentWithCopyService(file);

    public static void CreateNewDocumentWithCopyService(string fileName)
            {
                copyservice.Copy c = new copyservice.Copy();
                c.Url = "http://rajum-pc:40613/_vti_bin/copy.asmx";
                c.UseDefaultCredentials = true;

                byte[] myBinary = File.ReadAllBytes(fileName);
                string destination = "http://rajum-pc:40613/division1/shared documents/" + workflowProperties.Item.File.Name;
                string[] destinationUrl = { destination };

                copyservice.FieldInformation info1 = new copyservice.FieldInformation();
                info1.DisplayName = "Title";
                info1.InternalName = "Title";
                info1.Type = copyservice.FieldType.Text;
                info1.Value = "new title";

                copyservice.FieldInformation info2 = new copyservice.FieldInformation();
                info2.DisplayName = "Modified By";
                info2.InternalName = "Editor";
                info2.Type = copyservice.FieldType.User;
                info2.Value = "-1;#servername\\testmoss";

                copyservice.FieldInformation[] info = { info1, info2 };
                copyservice.CopyResult resultTest = new copyservice.CopyResult();
                copyservice.CopyResult[] result = { resultTest };

                try
                {
                    //When creating new content use the same URL in the SourceURI as in the Destination URL argument

                    c.CopyIntoItems(destination, destinationUrl, info, myBinary, out result);
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {

                }

            }
```

From: http://sharepointfieldnotes.blogspot.com/2009/09/uploading-content-into-sharepoint-let.html

Comment: let me try, but one question I need to copy a document to another sharepoint farm site. Will the copy.asmx code work in this scenario ?

Comment: I am referencing http://server/_vti_bin/copy.asmx in my code by this reference isnt working "copyservice.Copy" it cannot find the "Copy" class, whereas other classes it can see are "CopyResult" "CopySoapClient" etc

Comment: The same rules apply for authentication as with the listdata.svc where you used System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials.

Apart from that there should be no reason why it wouldn't work.

Comment: I got the Copy class now. Now trying your code.

Comment: I am running the above code, it runs but file is not copied to the second sharepoint server's shared document's folder.

Comment: Actually there are two seperate sharepoint farms. One is copying file to other

Comment: Can you debug the code to see that you can get hold of the source document and it is in fact uploading the file to destination that is causing the problem?

Comment: Yes debugged and its coming while uploading the document.

Comment: Ok its like my current server is in DMZ, and I wanna run this code from within this server to copy the file to my internal servers in domain and I am getting unable to connect to the remote server.

Comment: Currently I have used the webDav method

Comment: If you can help please do.

Comment: Can you connect to the source server (remote desktop preferred) and try to open the copy.asmx of the destination server using a browser. This is to ensure that there isn't any routing/firewall issues that would block traffic from source to destination.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/2289/discussion-between-jussi-palo-and-rhm)

Comment: Oops! I cannot even ping my internal machine from this DMZ machine :( but that is a policy of my company. Could you tell me how can I keep the files in sync between the two servers then.

Comment: Ping might be blocked, but if you cannot access the destination server using a browser from source machine then there's no way you can copy files directly from source server to destination server. You would need to use some service in the middle to which you would store the file from source servcer, and fetch it from the destination server. That's another story, unfortunately.

Answer (score 2):

The contenttype parameter in the **SetSaveStream** expects a valid [Mime type](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mime_type), which is ideally the type of file you are uploading, if you are not sure then I would recommend using **"*/*"** instead.

Your modified code should look like

```
sharePoint.AddToSharedDocuments(documentItem);

sharePoint.SetSaveStream(documentItem, file, false, "*/*", path);

sharePoint.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: SetSaveStream stream method is from lisdata.svc right ?

Comment: How to get a file from workflowproperties.item.file and put it in the method AddToSharedDocuments() method to get it saved in the shared documents